# @AutoConfigureBefore does not trigger

Tags: spring-boot

The intention of this project is to create hooks into Spring Boot's lifecycle, right before [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) executes its database schema changesets. The hooks will eventually be used to start / stop a Docker (or Docker-like) container with a Postgres instance. The project must be able to deal with:

- tests run from the IDE (IntellIJ, STS)
- tests run with Maven Surefire
- spring-boot:run
- executable JAR
- integration test on CI server

Given the above limitations, the best approach appeared to be to have an Auto-Configuration and instructing it to run before Liquibase.

The [Auto-Configuration class](https://github.com/robert-bor/auto-configuration-question/blob/master/src/main/java/nl/_42/autoconfig/Docker42AutoConfiguration.java) has been annotated:

```
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "docker_42", 
    name = "enabled", matchIfMissing = false)
@AutoConfigureBefore({LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.class })
public class Docker42AutoConfiguration {
```

[spring.factories](https://github.com/robert-bor/auto-configuration-question/blob/master/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories) has a single entry:

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
nl._42.autoconfig.Docker42AutoConfiguration
```

The entire (stripped down) project can be found here: https://github.com/robert-bor/auto-configuration-question

The results can be verified by either:

- setting up the project in your IDE & running a test, or
- executing spring-boot:run

In Spring Boot's log you will see Liquibase executing before the custom AutoConfiguration.

Note that various other routes have been tried (`ApplicationListener`, `RunListener`), but none played nice with all the required in-roads.

Pointers as to why `@AutoConfigureBefore` does not work in my project would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I think you misunderstand what "before" means. It has nothing to do about something actually running before something else, it's about registering a _bean definition_ before another configuration class has a chance to register one. Do I understand you thought you could use it to "run" something before something else? This is a configuration class, not an actual bean so that's no the same semantic.

Comment: [`@AutoConfigureBefore`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/1.4.1.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/AutoConfigureBefore.html) documentation says: "Hint for that an auto-configuration should be applied before other specified auto-configuration classes." The documented effect is exactly the effect I am looking for.

Comment: @stephane-nicoll, you, as a Spring Boot core committer, and given that I probably misunderstood `@AutoConfigureBefore`, what would you recommend for me to do given the above restrictions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're trying to apply a configuration semantic to some runtime constraints. Auto-configuration is about providing *bean definitions* in the context, something that will ultimately create bean instances that you can wire in your components.

Assume that you need bean `Foo` in order to auto-configure something. You need to make sure that `FooAutoConfiguration` runs before yours so that the context has a chance to contain a bean definition for `Foo`. That is explained in quite details in our [last Devoxx university](https://youtu.be/uof5h-j0IeE?t=59m56s).

The documentation you referenced in that comment does not imply runtime constraints in any way:

> Hint for that an auto-configuration should be applied before other specified auto-configuration classes.

*applying* the auto-configuration does not mean that the beans created by that configuration will effectively start before the beans created by another configuration. In other words, what you've done is making sure that your auto-configuration configures the context before the liquibase auto-configuration has a chance to do so. It does not imply, in any way, that the beans that will be created (we're not there yet) will be created in that order.

If that's what you want to do and you have no bean dependency, you can just forget about all that and create a bean lifecycle dependency instead. It can be tricky because liquibase may or may not be there but we essentially do that for `Hazelcast` (see [the auto-configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/00a18c32abe313f1caa4419a15cab924d70d87b6/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/hazelcast/HazelcastJpaDependencyAutoConfiguration.java#L47)). Basically we need to make sure that Hazelcast is started before the JPA container is started in case it wants to use Hazelcast as second level cache.

Comment: Thanks, Stephane. The video was informative. Reminds me to reserve a spot to Devoxx next year. The Hazelcast example indeed shows the way. Early results are promising.

Comment: the url of 'the auto-configuration' result in 404, could you plz fix it

Comment: Thanks for reporting it. It should be fixed.

Comment: thanks for explaintiation, it helps me solve https://stackoverflow.com/q/65321761/4695118, when I need trigger action before bean created